# How do you get an average of job history times?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, jobs

The following is a script I found online that has most of the elements of what I desire in the result set.  The only thing missing is how I can get an average of the run times over a decided time period, like a week, 10 days, 23 days, a month, etc.

I've done some searching, but what I've tried has failed in some way or another.  Further, my TSQL are weak, but I'm reading publications by Itzik Ben-gan to change this matter.  I'd truly appreciate any help that anyone can provide.

```
select job_name, run_datetime, run_duration
from
(
    select job_name, run_datetime,
        SUBSTRING(run_duration, 1, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(run_duration, 3, 2) + ':' +
        SUBSTRING(run_duration, 5, 2) AS run_duration
    from
    (
        select DISTINCT
            j.name as job_name, 
            run_datetime = CONVERT(DATETIME, RTRIM(run_date)) +  
                (run_time * 9 + run_time % 10000 * 6 + run_time % 100 * 10) / 216e4,
            run_duration = RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(varchar(6), run_duration), 6)
        from msdb..sysjobhistory h
        inner join msdb..sysjobs j
        on h.job_id = j.job_id
    ) t
) t
order by job_name, run_datetime
```

Comment: found the following link that is down the same path http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2850/querying-sql-server-agent-job-history-data/

Comment: this may also help you http://sqlcache.blogspot.com/2014/11/sql-server-agent-jobs-history.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Updated to satisfy the new requirement. Note that you may be tempted to use `CONVERT(TIME`, but resist - this is brittle, in the event any job runs longer than 24 hours.

```
SELECT 
  job_name = name, 
  avg_sec  = rd,
  avg_mmss = CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),rd / 60) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),rd % 60), 2)
FROM
(
  SELECT
    j.name, 
    rd = AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' 
       + CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),run_duration),6),5,0,':'),3,0,':')))
  FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory AS h
  INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS j
  ON h.job_id = j.job_id
  WHERE h.step_id = 0
  GROUP BY j.name
) AS t
ORDER BY job_name;
```

Comment: I don't believe this is logically correct. The history table contains a 0 (zero) step with the step_name of **(job outcome)** This row contains the total run duration of all the steps in the job. You just need to average these rows. Subquery should look like this:

Comment: SELECT
    j.name, 
    rd = AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' 
       + CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),run_duration),6),5,0,':'),3,0,':')))
  FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory AS h
  INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS j
  ON h.job_id = j.job_id **AND h.step_id = 0**
  GROUP BY j.name

Comment: @AWEInCA I think you're onto something, however one problem with relying on step 0 is that you have to wait for a job to finish before collecting its duration. If this is to be used as an early indicator for a job that is currently running longer than it should (or at least longer than the average), you'll still want to look outside of step 0.

Comment: This is the exact query I'm actually looking for. Thanks Aaron.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks Aaron!  One thing to point out, the 3rd column is returning "avg_mmss" instead of "avg_hhmm".

Answer (score 0):

Updated Script

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Temp;

SELECT
 h.job_id,
 msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(run_date,run_time) as RunDate,
 CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 6) +  CAST(run_duration as varchar(6)), 6),5,2))
 + CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 6) +  CAST(run_duration as varchar(6)), 6),3,2)) * 60
 + CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 6) +  CAST(run_duration as varchar(6)), 6),1,2)) * 60 * 60 As TotalRunSeconds 
into #Temp
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h
Where step_id = 0;

SELECT
  job_name = name,
  avg_sec  = rd,
  avg_mmss = CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),rd / 60) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),rd % 60), 2)
FROM
(
  SELECT
    j.name,
    rd = AVG(
        DATEDIFF(SECOND, RunDate, DATEADD(SECOND, TotalRunSeconds, RunDate)))
  FROM #Temp AS h
  INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS j
  ON h.job_id = j.job_id where j.name='Maintenance - Backups - USER - FULL'
  GROUP BY j.name
) AS t
ORDER BY job_name;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Temp;
```