# Need to know how to check how much time job takes to complete execution

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

How we can determine how much time a job takes to execute in sql server, I have a job which runs every hour, I also having some performance issue so I wanted to check if the performance issue is because the job is running or something else and that is why I have to check how much time job is taking to finish.

Job is basically to update the table.

Any help or tips will be very helpful!!!!!

Comment: You can add new table and hold write execution time there. Or you can add audit columns (modified) to updated table and query updated table after jobeing execute. Or use profiler.

Comment: Are you talking about Agent jobs?

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik yes

Comment: Duplicate? http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/89280/32281